# select posts from the last month

Tags: php, mysql

In a table `posts` I have a column named `date` format - `datetime` - `current timestamp` and need to select posts from the last month only.

All dates in the column are from december 2016. for example - `2016-12-09 04:25:00`

```
<?php
$start = strtotime("-1 month"); // 1488285716
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts where date > " . $start . " order by...");
?>
```

But all posts are selected!  Resulut should be zero.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
$start = strtotime("-1 month");
$date =  date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $start);
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts where date > " . $date . " order by...");
```

Comment: You can do this from pure sql without any need for formatting the datetime in php.